# R: How to run regression (glm function) with some coefficients specified?

Tags: r, regression, glm

Suppose I have one dependent variable, and 4 independent variables. I suspect only 3 of the independent variables are significant, so I use the glm(y~ x1 + x2 + x3...) function. Then I get some coefficients for these variables. Now I want to run glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4), but I want to specify that the x1, x2, x3 coefficients remain the same. How could I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use offsets: `glm(y~x4+offset(coef1*x1+coef2*x2+coef3*x3))` -- although it's not at all clear to me whether what you're doing is a sensible *statistical* approach.

Comment: I suppose you could do this via offset terms. These are terms that are set to have a coefficient value of 1, hence you can multiply each variable by its coefficient from the first model and use those new variables in offset terms in the model, with `x4` being the only non-offset term which will get an estimated coefficient. But I'm not certain you *should* be doing this.

Comment: if you give a reproducible example I'll expand my comment to an answer (or someone else can ...)

Comment: It might help to provide some information about why you want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can fit a model where some of the independent variables have fixed parameters. What you can do is create a new variable `y2` that equals the predicted value of your first model with `x1+x2+x3`. Then, you can fit a second model `y~y2+x4` to include it as an independent variable along with `x4`.

So basically, something like this:

```
m1 <- glm(y~x1+x2+x3...)
data$y2 <- predict(glm, newdata=data)
m2 <- glm(y~y2+x4...)
```